# Where can I find examples of everyday objects built in Lego?

Tags: building

Suppose for example I am interested in creative ways people have made trees, or minifig scale furniture, or just architectural details like windows. Is there some encyclopedia that organizes pictures this way?

Comment: I've been getting a lot of inspiration for this sort of thing from the LEGO video games, which have quite a lot of "destructible" furniture/sets.

Answer (score 15):

### The Lego Ideas Book

Recently released last month (19th Sep 2011). Written with the help of adult Lego Fans. I've had a look through the book myself. The book has six chapters focussing on transport, buildings, space, kingdoms, adventure and 'useful makes'. The buildings chapter in-particular focusses on every day objects.

[image]

[The LEGO Ideas Book, hmillington @Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hmillington/6214713367/)

Answer (score 5):

### Flickr

The photography site has a large community of Lego Fans who share there creations. There is an entire group dedicated to [Minifigure scale furniture](http://www.flickr.com/groups/legominifigfurniture/).

Answer (score 4):

If you can go, try attending an AFOL convention. Brickcon is always a great source of inspiration to me. You'll see great examples of everyday objects & building styles & you have access to some of the model builders themselves. You can get helpful hints from them that even the excellent answers mentioned above can't provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit the website [buildingexamples.com](http://buildingexamples.com) A lot of examples are there with step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get ideas and suggestions from the [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/) website. You can see what others have built and get instructions for them.